# Should I use preposition 'at' or 'on' for this affirmative sentence?

Tags: prepositions

sentence:

> 1) You should train yourself **at** writing
>
> 2) You should train yourself **on** writing

question:

> **Which preposition I should use for this sentence OR both of them could be used in this context?**

Answer (score 1):

Neither. The correct preposition should be "in", as evidenced by the [OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/training):

> training (**in** something/**in** doing something)
>   *Few candidates had received any training **in** management.*

Even though this is the page on the noun, you can see that *in* is used whenever you're talking about the subject matter in which you receive training.